# Preloading Image Bug in IE6-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, preloading

Page in question: http://phwsinc.com/our-work/one-rincon-hill.asp

In IE6-8, when you click the left-most thumbnail in the gallery, the image never loads. If you click the thumbnail a second time, then it will load. I'm using jQuery, and here's my code that's powering the gallery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// PROJECT PHOTO GALLERY
var thumbs = $('.thumbs li a');
var photoWrapper = $('div.photoWrapper');

if (thumbs.length) {
    thumbs.click( function(){
        photoWrapper.addClass('loading');

        var img_src =   $(this).attr('href');

        // The two lines below are what cause the bug in IE. They make the gallery run much faster in other browsers, though.
        var new_img =   new Image();
        new_img.src =   img_src;

        var photo =     $('#photo');
        photo.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            photo.attr('src', img_src);
            photo.load(function() {
                photoWrapper.removeClass('loading');
                photo.fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });

        return false;
    });
}
});
```

A coworker told me that he's always had problems with the js Image() object, and advised me to just append an `<img />` element inside of a div set to `display:none;`, but that's a little messy for my tastes--I liked using the Image() object, it kept things nice and clean, no unnecessary added HTML markup.

Any help would be appreciated. It still works without the image preloading, so if all else fails I'll just wrap the preloading in an `if !($.browser.msie){ }` and call it a day.

Comment: If I were you I would set up the "load" handler for `#photo` separately, instead of doing it on each click like that.

Comment: I don't quite understand--could you provide a code sample? Doesn't the load handler need to run everytime a thumbnail is clicked (and thus a new image is being loaded)? Otherwise it would only run 1 time on $(document).ready().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've fixed this already, but I wanted to see if I could get the pre-loading to work in IE as well.

try changing this

```
photo.fadeOut('slow', function() { 
  photo.attr('src', img_src); 
  photo.load(function() { 
    photoWrapper.removeClass('loading'); 
    photo.fadeIn('slow'); 
  }); 
});
```

to this

```
photo.fadeOut('slow', function() { 
  photo.attr('src', img_src); 

  if (photo[0].complete){
    photoWrapper.removeClass('loading'); 
    photo.fadeIn('slow'); 
  } else {  
    photo.load(function() { 
      photoWrapper.removeClass('loading'); 
      photo.fadeIn('slow'); 
    }); 
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to get to this, been quite busy.

Your approach worked! For the most part...the only problem is, every once and while there's some sort of weird flicker...but I can't pin it down, it's difficult to replicate. Oh well, I'm using your new code now in any case, thanks a bunch!